# Changing object data using with_mode method

Tags: origen-sdk

I have added some [ChipModes](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/modes/#Mode) as follows:

```
  add_mode :mode1
  add_mode :mode2
```

When I set the DUT mode to :mode1 I want to have some clocks change their set point.

```
  with_mode :mode1 do
    clocks(:clk1).setpoint = 1.0.Ghz
    clocks(:clk2).setpoint = 1.2.Ghz
  end

  with_mode :mode2 do
    clocks(:clk1).setpoint = 2.0.Ghz
    clocks(:clk2).setpoint = 2.4.Ghz
  end
```

What I expected was that when the DUT chip mode was set to either :mode1 or :mode 2, the clock values would change.  But instead it seems these code blocks are executed regardless of the DUT chip mode.

[image]

The clocks end up getting set to the values in the second with_mode code block.  Is there a way to define mode dependent actions that only get executed when the mode is set?

** EDIT **

Using [this doc](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/appcallbacks/) as a model, I added the on_mode_changed callback to the [origen/model.rb file](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/master/lib/origen/model.rb) as so:

```
# Set the current mode configuration of the current model
def current_mode=(id)
  @current_mode = id.is_a?(ChipMode) ? id.id : id
  Origen.app.listeners_for(:on_mode_changed).each do |listener|
    listener.on_mode_changed(mode: @current_mode)
  end
  @current_mode
end
alias_method :mode=, :current_mode=
```

When I set the breakpoint, directly after I set the mode I do see the mode has changed and that the DUT responds to the callback method, but the callback method does not get called.

[image]
[image]

Here is the callback method within the DUT scope:

```
def on_mode_changed(options)
  binding.pry
  puts 'found callback method'
  return if options[:mode].nil?
end
```

** UPDATE **

The code works above, thx!

Comment: That doc is describing how to add a callback point within your application code. Within Origen core, the API is Origen.app.listeners_for (note the .app.)

Comment: Callbacks probably don't work before the target environment is loaded, i.e. when in the dut init method. Set the mode in the on_create callback instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with_mode` method does not do what you are thinking here. All it does is set the mode for the duration of the given `do ... end` block (and which is executed there and then), but it does not auto-magically create a live linkage between anything you define within the block and the current mode that is in scope.

I think what you really want is an `on_mode_changed` callback.

Origen would need to be updated to invoke such a callback whenever the mode changes. That is easy to do, here are some examples of how to implement a callback: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=listeners_for&type=

Your application code would then change to something like:

```rb
SETPOINTS = { mode1: { clk1: 1.0.Ghz, clk2: 1.2.Ghz },
              mode2: { clk1: 2.0.Ghz, clk2: 2.4.Ghz } }

def on_mode_changed(mode)
  [:clk1, :clk2].each { |clk| clocks(clk).setpoint = SETPOINTS[mode][clk] }
end
```

You may also consider whether live updating parameters might work for you here, these are somewhat of a magic solution that is looking for a reason to exist - http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/parameters/#Live_Updating_Parameters

Comment: would you recommend persistent or regular callbacks? @Ginty

Comment: For this case the callback listener should just be the model itself, so it would be a regular callback.